# unable to see the first address using web3.eth.getAddress()

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask

**I tried to see all address using**

`web3.eth.getAccounts()`

It's run perfectly. Next I tried to see the first address using

`web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(accounts) {return accounts[0]})`

It's also worked well. But now I want to use this address according to their index.

when I use `getAccounts[0]`or `getAccounts[1]` sometimes it's work, sometimes not.

So is there any specific way to **use those address using index?**

Comment: Well, there is no `getAccounts` array (or object) anywhere, so using it with `[]` is obviously not going to work. This has nothing to do with Ethereum BTW, it is a simple Javascript matter. You can't take a function and expect it to "behave like an array"!

Comment: yeah I understand. By the way it's solved. simple just using  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts().. After that I'm able to see addresses using accounts[0]/accounts[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to use the `web3.eth.gethAccounts()` method with an index based on which account you want to return.

Reading the documentation at https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth.html#getaccounts the only parameter accepted by the method is the `[callback]` function so i think that you cannot use the index as an input parameter.

Hope this helps.